# No Database Selected in PHP MySqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have switched to MySQLi and am having some issues when loading up a login page. I get the error "No database selected".

This is my connection code.

```
<?php
// config

$config['host'] = "";

$config['user'] = "";

$config['pass'] = "";

$config['db'] = "";

// the @ sign is an error supressor, meaning we can use our own error messages, this connects and selects db
@($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect(
    "$config[host]", "$config[user]", "$config[pass]"
)) 
or die("error :".((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))."");
@((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . $config['db'])) 
or die("error:".((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))."");

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: You can pass through the database name in your connection if you want. Maybe that's the trick? This code is so impenetrably unreadable that you really should try and simplify it. I don't know what you're doing there with `@` but it looks very, very dangerous.

Comment: Not sure what you think you are doing, apart from making your code almost completely unreadable and unmaintainable

Answer (score -1):

Check the code below.

```
// config
$config['host'] = "localhost"; // host name of your mysql server

$config['user'] = "root"; // your mysql username

$config['pass'] = ""; // your mysql password

$config['db'] = "sb_posts"; // the database your table is in.

// the @ sign is an error supressor, meaning we can use our own error messages, this connects and selects db
@($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = msqli_connect("".$config['host']."","".$config['user']."","".$config['pass']."","".$config['db'] ."")) or die("There was an error connecting to the database, MySql said:<br />".((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))."");
@((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . $config['db'])) or die("There was an error connecting to the database, MySql said:<br />".((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))."");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $u = 'root', $p = '', $db = 'db')
    {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $u;
    $this->pwd = $p;
    $this->db = $db;

    //connect to the database
    $this->conxn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user  , $this->pwd, $this->db)
                    or trigger_error($this->error = mysqli_error($this->conxn));


}
```